# RecyclerView in React Native: notifyItemInserted() and notifyDataSetChanged() have no effect

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am experimenting with integrating a Firebase-backed RecyclerView in a React Native app. With hardcoded data it works well, but upon inserting rows loaded dynamically and calling either notifyItemInserted() or notifyDataSetChanged() on the RecyclerView.Adapter, the RecyclerView itself does not reflect the change. This manifests as an initial blank view until the app's refresh button is tapped, which has the sole effect of re-rendering the RecyclerView from the React Native side, or until scrolling or a screen orientation change.

After reading through a dozen or more questions on this site about similar issues not involving React Native and having tried most of the common solutions, I suspect this issue is related specifically to React Native.

Finding a solution to this could be helpful to many, given the ongoing performance issues with React Native's list view implementations.

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Post> mDataset;

    public PostsAdapter(ArrayList<Post> list){
        mDataset = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout mPostView;
        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout v) {
            super(v);
            mPostView = v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PostsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) holder.mPostView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setText(mDataset.get(position).title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}

 public class RNPostsViewManager extends SimpleViewManager{
    private ArrayList<Post> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "AndroidPostsView";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private PostsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Query initialDataQuery;
    private ChildEventListener initialDataListener;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @UiThread
    public void addPost (Post p){
        mDataset.add(p);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mDataset.size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView createViewInstance( ThemedReactContext context) {

        mAdapter = new PostsAdapter(mDataset);

        mRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(context){
            @Override
            protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
                super.onAttachedToWindow();
                initialDataQuery.addChildEventListener(initialDataListener);
            }
        };

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context.getCurrentActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        DividerItemDecoration mDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, 1);
        mDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context.getCurrentActivity(), R.drawable.sep));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDecoration);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        initialDataQuery = mDatabase.child("wp-posts").orderByChild("unixPostDate").limitToFirst(100);
        initialDataListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Post p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                addPost(p);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        return mRecyclerView;
    }

}

// layout file post.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you insert a log in the `addPost(p)` method?

Comment: What should be logged in there?

Comment: Just added a RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver and logged from that. The onChanged() method is never invoked.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know the same - wether data is being inserted to mDataset or not.

Comment: Data is definitely being inserted, as the getItemCount() method returns  the correct value after scrolling or orientation change. But getItemCount() is never invoked after a call to addPost() and hence notifyItemInserted().

Comment: I don't know if this should make a difference, but try removing the `@UiThread` attribute from your `addPost()` method and running it again.

Comment: Running on UI thread or not seems to make no difference here. I've tried other ways besides the @UIThread annotation.

Comment: I agree. Your code seems fine. I don't know what's causing your problem.

Comment: So the onItemRangeInserted observers are getting fired when addPost(p) is. That's something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `requestLayout` does not work well when the `RecyclerView` is a native UI component.

The following hack made all those issues go away:

I now overwrite the `requestLayout` method inside my `RecyclerView`.
Then before any `notify*` method, or even `scrollToPosition` calls or any method that invokes a re-layout, I allow my custom `requestLayout` method to force a re-layout.

The end result looks like this:

```
private boolean mRequestedLayout = false;


public void aMethodThatUpdatesStuff(int indexToUpdate, ReadableMap updatedChild) {
    final SPAdapter adapter = (SPAdapter) getAdapter();
    mRequestedLayout = false;
    adapter.updateDataAtIndex(indexToUpdate, updatedChild); // <-- this runs notifyItemChanged inside
}

@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout();
    // We need to intercept this method because if we don't our children will never update
    // Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371866/recyclerview-wont-update-child-until-i-scroll
    if (!mRequestedLayout) {
        mRequestedLayout = true;
        this.post(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRequestedLayout = false;
                layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
                onLayout(false, getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root view in ReactNative is ReactRootView which `onlayout` is an empty method.

when call `notifyDatasetChanged` in RecyclerView, it's actually request `layout` to relayout its children. And the layout method will call `super.layout` to travel the whole view tree first. So that't a problem when the root view is ReactRootView.

You can manually call `RecyclerView.onlayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)` to trigger its children relayout to make notifyDatasetChanged work.

Comment: But `onLayout` does not even get invoked inside the `ReactRootView` when a notify* runs, I don't think that's the issue here.
:/