# RecyclerView won't update child until I scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, react-native, recyclerview-layout

I think I've read pretty much **all the answers** to all of the similar SO questions, and **NONE of them** seem to be working for me. It's driving me nuts, and I've spent too much time on this.

I'm implementing a `RecyclerView` [here](https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-synchronous-list/blob/master/lib/android/src/main/java/com/sudoplz/rnsynchronouslistmanager/Views/List/SPRecyclerView.java) and I can't for the life of me update it's children. What happens is that after I update nothing changes on the screen, *UNLESS* I start scrolling. Once I scroll it updates **perfectly**.

This is my code:

```
public void updateDataAtIndex(final int indexToUpdate, ReadableMap updatedChild) {
    if (updatedChild != null) {
        if (this.data != null && this.data.size() > indexToUpdate) {
            this.data.set(indexToUpdate, updatedChild);
            final SPAdapter self = this;
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Updating: "+indexToUpdate);
                    self.notifyItemChanged(indexToUpdate);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the full adapter:
https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-synchronous-list/blob/master/lib/android/src/main/java/com/sudoplz/rnsynchronouslistmanager/Views/List/SPAdapter.java#L109

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That was a react-native issue `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

I've resolved this by intercepting `requestLayout` like so:

```
protected boolean mRequestedLayout = false;

@Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        super.requestLayout();
        // We need to intercept this method because if we don't our children will never update
        // Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371866/recyclerview-wont-update-child-until-i-scroll
        if (!mRequestedLayout) {
            mRequestedLayout = true;
            this.post(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRequestedLayout = false;
                    layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
                    onLayout(false, getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

FINALLY it works..
Credit goes to [this](https://github.com/godness84/react-native-recyclerview-list/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/github/godness84/RNRecyclerViewList/RecyclerViewBackedScrollView.java#L357) unsung hero who discovered the workaround.

Comment: This works! I was having the same issue, thank you. I'd mention that you need to declare mRequestedLayout somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save me a lot of pain.

Comment: I'm super happy to hear that @DanielJosePadillaPeña

Comment: For me, I didn't even see `refreshLayout` called until I scrolled.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/issues/118

Thank you so much <3

Comment: I did not have luck with this. I posted an answer above that works with recyclerviews

Comment: Not a React Native issue for me but yes, it does work!

Comment: This can't be just real! It took me 3 days to find this. I tried everything. Including re-writing thread management of view manager

Comment: I know right? I can totally relate!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

This forces the layout to refresh the items entirely. Adjust it as need for your case.

```
fun RecyclerView.forceLayout() {

  // Tell adapter the data has changed
  adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

  // Force the layout to move
  // This will render all items in view again
  scrollBy(0, 0)

}
```

*You'd think React **Native** would handle **native** UI correctly..*