# when to setAdapter for custom recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-databinding

I am trying to build an encapsulated RecyclerView. I use databinding to get the data that will be displayed (i.e. the data that needs to go to the Adapter).

I am struggling to find the right place in my Recycler to set up my Adapter. If I put it constructor or in onFinishedInflate(), the databinding has not been set up yet. If I put it in onLayout() it kind of works, but the RecyclerView doesn't display the items until after the user interacts with the RecyclerView for the first time (not sure why).

```
class MyRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    private var binding: MyBinding? = null

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int)
    {
    if (binding == null) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(this)
        val adapter = MyAdapter(binding!!.mydata.DataList)
        setAdapter(adapter)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(getContext()))
    }
}
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="myData"
            type="com.example.xxx.XXX" />
    </data>

    <com.example.xxx.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </com.example.xxx.MyRecyclerView>
</layout>
```

I acknowledge that onLayout seems like an odd place to do it.

I did play with converting the CustomView to a Fragment, but apparently it is illegal to bind data to a Fragment (in the xml at least).

So ... is there a good/better time to initially set up the adapter from bound data for a custom RecyclerView?

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't looks a good design.Separator your adapter from `MyRecyclerView` .

Comment: Some object somewhere needs to instantiate and assign the RecyclerView.Adapter to the RecyclerView. My RecyclerView has the raw DataList bound to it, and it seems like how that list is handled is an implementation detail of the RecyclerView (i.e. that it requires a RecyclerView.Adapter to digest the data).  Is this thinking wrong? (A sincere question) Which class/function should do it (given that the Activity might be an arbitrary distance up the view tree)? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I found a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955741/support-recyclerview-doesnt-show-anything-until-touched